# jQuery conditional add and remove CSS property

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have a CSS border property in place currently (border-left: 1px), and onClick, I have it removed via the first jQuery function below.
How can I set this up so that my second function will add back the property upon the second click? It should switch back and forth per click.

```
$(function(){
    $('#button').click(function() {    
        $('#button-2').css('border-left','none');
    });   
    $('#button').click(function() {
        $('#button-2').css('border-left','1px');
    });
});
```

**I have now included the original code**: [www.jsfiddle.net/tonynggg/frnYf/12](http://jsfiddle.net/tonynggg/frnYf/12)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Would it be easier to define a css class:

```
.button { border-left: 1px; }
.buttonClicked { border-left: none; }
```

And then use the jQuery [toggleClass](http://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/)

So your code would be:

```
$(function(){
    $('#button').click(function() {    
        $('#button-2').toggleClass('buttonClicked');
    });   
});
```

That would then toggle your alternate css class on an off when it's clicked. If nothing else, this should get you pointed in the right direction.

Comment: This is the best way, much better than hard-coding CSS into javascript files.

Comment: Interesting. Wasn't aware of the `toggleClass` method.

Comment: @M_M Unfortunately I couldn't get that to work. Here's the original code: http://jsfiddle.net/tonynggg/frnYf/12/

Comment: there is no `toggleCss` method. Take a look at http://jsfiddle.net/frnYf/16/ also, I would consider only creating one click event handler for #button.

Comment: @Tony my pleasure! Glad I could assist :)

Answer (score 1):

First, create a class that has the border:

```
.borderclass
{
   border-left:1px black solid;
}
```

And then,

```
$(function(){
$('#button').click(function() {    
    if ($('#button-2').hasClass('borderclass'))
        $('#button-2').removeClass('borderclass');
    else
        $('#button-2').addClass('borderclass');
    });   

});
```

Comment: This code doesn't work unfortunately. Although it looks like the correct solution, I think maybe because the "hasClass" is not functional because #button-2 is not a class?